# AJAX to refresh user online in chat script

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, chat

i found chat script for my website at [here](https://github.com/aditya3098/Aditya-s-ChatBox)
the script already work and refresh every message, but the problem is the list of user online did not refresh every new user logged in.

ajax code

```
// Now let's load chatroom's active users       
function load_users(){
    // Let's use AJAX also to get chatroom's users
    $.ajax({
        url: "includes/actions.php?act=getusers",
        cache: false    
    });
}
setInterval(load_messages, 500);
setInterval(load_users, 500);
```

actions.php script

```
function get_users(){

    global $tb_satker;
    // Let's get all info from "auth" table
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tb_satker WHERE status!=''";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    if(!$query){
        echo "Can not get users from database.";
    }else{
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $namasatker=$row['nama_satker'];
            echo "<li><i class=\"icon-user\"></i>$namasatker</li>";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your function doesn't display the response anywhere.

Comment: the complete script can be found here http://forum.codecall.net/topic/49763-simple-chatroom-with-php-jquery/ i think something missed at load_users() ajax script

Comment: you probably need to add something random to the `URL` to prevent the browser from caching

Comment: @RST That's what `cache: false` does

Comment: @Barmar you are right, completely overlooked that line. Formatting is a bit off.

Comment: The code at that site is wrong. You need a `success:` function in `load_users()`, similar to the one in `load_messages()`.

Comment: @Barmar can you assist me to fix the code please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a success function that displays the returned HTML:

```
function load_users(){
    // Let's use AJAX also to get chatroom's users
    $.ajax({
        url: "includes/actions.php?act=getusers",
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) {
            $("#onlineusers").html(response);
        }
    });
}
```